# How to print dictionary key if it exists and its value of lists in specified format?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to print a dictionary key (if it exists) and its value of lists in this format (some records have a "fourth string", "fifth string"), etc. :

```
    First Name
    2018-11-05 10:12:15
    First string
    Second string
    Third string
```

I tried to code it this way but it didn't work

```
name = {'First Name':['2018-11-05 10:12:15','First string', 'Second String', 
        'Third String']} 

 answer = input("Enter name: ")
            for k, v in name.items():
                if answer == k:
                    print(k, v)
                else:
                    break
```

Comment: It works for me without any change..  what error you got or where you doubt about logical mistake??

Comment: you might want to have a look at the `dict` method [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Comment: it works the first time a name is searched but subsequent searches would not yield anything even if the name is in the dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the key directly and print the list this way to match your format:

```
if answer in name:
    print(answer)
    for item in name[answer]:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the value for dictionary key, then you need to iterate through the array values:

```
answer = input("Enter name: ")
if answer in name:
    value = name[answer]
    for item in value:
        print (item)
```